# Convert pandas cut operation to a regular string

Tags: python, pandas

I get the foll. output from a pandas cut operation:

```
0        (0, 20]
1        (0, 20]
2        (0, 20]
3        (0, 20]
4        (0, 20]
5        (0, 20]
6        (0, 20]
7        (0, 20]
8        (0, 20]
9        (0, 20]
```

How can I convert the (0, 20] to 0 - 20?

I am doing this:

```
.str.replace('(', '').str.replace(']', '').str.replace(',', ' -')
```

Any better approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

assuming the output was assigned to a variable `cut`

```
cut.astype(str)
```

To remove bracketing

```
cut.astype(str).str.strip('()[]')
```

Comment: thanks @piRsquared. .astype(str) changes it from categorical to object dtype but does not remove the brackets

Comment: @user308827 added a solution.

Comment: I think this is the better solution.  The solution above is problematic if lots of categories.

Answer (score 10):

Use the `labels` parameter of [`pd.cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
pd.cut(df['some_col'], bins=[0,20,40,60], labels=['0-20', '20-40', '40-60'])
```

I don't know what your exact `pd.cut` command looks like, but the code above should give you a good idea of what to do.

Example usage:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'some_col': range(5, 56, 5)})
df['cut'] = pd.cut(df['some_col'], bins=[0,20,40,60], labels=['0-20','20-40','40-60'])
```

Example output:

```
    some_col    cut
0          5   0-20
1         10   0-20
2         15   0-20
3         20   0-20
4         25  20-40
5         30  20-40
6         35  20-40
7         40  20-40
8         45  40-60
9         50  40-60
10        55  40-60
```