# Turning integer into strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I have a dataset that has a column called Founded. The founded column contains a variety of years in which a company was founded also the datatype for the column is int64. I have a for loop that is supposed to alter the column based on the if statements

```
for i in range(2253):
    if type(df['Founded'].iloc[i])== int :
        if df['Founded'].iloc[i]>2000.0 :
            df['Founded'].iloc[i]= 'After 2000'
        elif  1950.0 <df['Founded'].iloc[i]<=2000.0 :
            df['Founded'].iloc[i]= 'Between 1951-2000'
        elif  1900.0 <df['Founded'].iloc[i]<=1950.0 :
            df['Founded'].iloc[i]= 'Between 1901-1950'
        elif df['Founded'].iloc[i]<1900.0 :
            df['Founded'].iloc[i]= 'Before 1900'
    else :
        df['Founded'].iloc[i]=None
    i=i+1
```

But after I run the code and check the column Founded everthing is changed into Nan. Any suggestions as to what I am do wrong?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/38927645/6692898

Comment: Try `if type(df['Founded'].iloc[i])== numpy.int64`

Comment: None of those solutions worked. I can't use the cut method and when I try adding == numpy.int64 it says "numpy.int64" is not definded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the type is really `int` and not any other type (print it out during the for loop). Here's another implementation (runs fine for me):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def transform_func(val):
    if isinstance(val, int):
        if val > 2000:
            val = 'After 2000'
        elif 1950 < val <= 2000:
            val = 'Between 1951-2000'
        elif 1900 < val <= 1950:
            val = 'Between 1901-1950'
        elif val < 1900:
            val = 'Before 1900'
        return val
    return None

# dummy data
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Founded': ['foo', 1942, 1632, 2026, 'bar', None, np.nan]}
)

df['Founded'] = df['Founded'].apply(transform_func)

df['Founded']

# >> out:
# 0                 None
# 1    Between 1901-1950
# 2          Before 1900
# 3           After 2000
# 4                 None
# 5                 None
# 6                 None
# Name: Founded, dtype: object
```

So instead of writing a for loop, a function is defined (with the if-statements) and then passed to the apply method (which will apply the function to each row in the column).

Comment: The code runs now thank you. I noticed that when I ran the following code df=df.replace(-1.0,np.NaN)
df=df.replace(-1,np.NaN)
df=df.replace('-1',np.NaN)                                                                                                       before running the function I would get an error. it would change the year from "1980" to "1980." Not sure as to why that was happening

Comment: Hmm, that seems strage. Although I'm not quite sure what you mean. Is it possible for you show me the error message, as well as the code you ran?

Comment: The code I ran was the function for loop from above. Which did not give me an error but it returned none for everything. Before I ran the for loop I ran the code "df=df.replace(-1,np.NaN)" but I noticed that is where the problem began. However, If I run the function before running the replace nan function, There are no issues.

Comment: ah okay, I thought there was a problem with the code snippet I provided :-)